# The max module of holomorphic function on a complex segment

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function and let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $\theta \in [0 , 2\pi]$ and let $D=\{ z \backslash  z=z_0 + r \cdot e^{i\theta}, r \in [-1,1]  \}$ (the segment of center $z_0$ and lenght $2$)

I would like to know if is true that
$$
\max_{z \in D}|f(z)|
=
\max\{|f(z_0 - e^{i\theta})|,|f(z_0 + e^{i\theta})|\}
$$

Comment: You have forgotten two signs of absolute values (in the second "max"). Try $f(z)=z^2-1$, $z_0=\theta=0$.

Comment: Why would it be true ? Do you know the maximum modulus principle ? What do you obtain when applying it to (the neighborhood of) a segment ?

Comment: ok thank @Kelenner i understand that it is not true

Comment: thanks @reuns i understand